# Reinstallation or redeployment after hardware crash?

Tags: windows-server-2008

What is the best way to bring back the server online after hardware crash. I suppose image won't work after hardware change.

So I like to know what is the fastest way to bring everything back.
I've the following software running on the server:

1. MSSQL
2. IIS
3. Custom Server Software
4. FTP Server

Then there is configuration:

- Registering asp.net 4.0
- Configuration files for server software (these can be put back from backup)
- Configuration if windows firewall.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the image file type?

Comment: backup software that comes with windows 2008 server.

Comment: What hardware component crashed?  And what hardware are you replacing it with?  What deployment systems do you have?  How long is your restore-from-backup time?  This is just too broad and subjective.

Comment: Windows backup in 2008 and later support restores to dissimilar hardware. You should read the manual before you make assumptions like that.

Comment: Nothing crashed at the moment, but I want to reduce downtime in case of a hardware crash. But few months a go HDD crashed.

Comment: Then you test your backups.  Do some restore testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the point of the backup if you're not going to restore it when trouble arises? Do a restore and be done with it!

Comment: Sometimes server needs a clean re-install of OS, how to quickly restore all the server software and their configuration?

Comment: Um... reinstall them? The only thing that will make it go faster is documentation about the previous installation and practice.

Comment: I've the re-installation notes, but still that takes long time. I was hoping some kind of restore feature that can restore the software with configuration on a clean re-installed OS.

Comment: Disaster scenarios are why you have backups.

Comment: You could develop installation scripts for everything, which is great for making lots of the same thing, ie desktops. What you're trying to do isn't worth the effort.

Comment: I guess I'll go with simple restore. But my worry is if there is hardware change after crash and system restore won't work or it maybe have problems due to hardware/driver changes. I guess I can just restore files I require in program files, but then they won't show installed in the installed programmed list.

Comment: Somebody said there is option in Windows 2008 R2 to restore to a machine with different hardware. Not sure how that works, I'm trying to find detailed documentation about it.

Comment: Here is another topic, with different hardware it is not supported. http://serverfault.com/questions/133476/restoring-windows-server-2008-to-a-different-computer

I'm back to square one, how to restore applications to a different hardware.